# RestKit many-to-many with Core Data: it works, but am I doing it right?

Tags: cocoa, restkit

I'm new to RestKit. I'm trying to map a many-to-many relationship, between entities Space and User. For the purposes of this question, assume all the Space objects are in the Core Data store correctly already.

In the REST API, I can make a single call to get all the users for a given space. First of all, when I initialise my network fetching class, I set up a mapping appropriate for parsing a list of users:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping *teamMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:self.manager.objectStore.primaryManagedObjectContext] inManagedObjectStore:self.manager.objectStore];

[teamMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"userID"];
[teamMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
teamMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"userID";
[self.manager.mappingProvider setMapping:teamMapping forKeyPath:@"users.user"];
```

Then, to populate the links for the users to the spaces, I do this:

```
NSArray *spaces = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Space"] error:nil];

for (QBSpace *space in spaces)
{
    [self.manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"space/%@/users", space.wikiName] usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
        loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects){
            space.team = nil;
            for (QBUser *user in objects)
            {
                [space addTeamObject:user];
            }

        };
    }];
}
```

That is, I manually add the space->user link based on the returned array of objects.

Is that the correct way to do it? It seems to work fine, but I'm worried I'm missing a trick with regards to RestKit doing things automatically.

The returned XML for the file in question looks like

```
<users type="array">
<user>
<id>aPrimaryKey</id>
<login>loginName</login>
<login_name warning="deprecated">loginName</login_name>
<name>Real Name</name>
</user>
```

So there is nothing in the returned file to indicate the space that I'm trying to link to: I passed that in in the URL I requested, but there's nothing in the returned document about it, which is why I came up with this block based solution.

To all the RestKit users, does this look like an acceptable way to form many-to-many links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works, it's ok?

You could think about having a Space custom ManagedObject. Have it respond to the `RKObjectLoaderDelegate`.

Then, when you get the reply, you could trigger the `loadAtResourcePath` from within its
`objectLoader:didLoadObject:(id)object` or `objectLoader:didLoadObjectDictionary:`
methods.

You could also make your Space class respond to the delegates from User and then tie them into their space at that point?

It might be better, but that would depend on what you are trying to achieve. Food for thought anyway. :)

Comment: Is it OK to have the model object triggering web service requests? That seems a bit like it violates MVC to me. Definitely one to think about. Do you know of any examples or links to the RestKit docs that handle many-to-many relationships with Core Data?

Comment: I know what you mean. I started out with Classes like GetSpace, doing the web service work, but when I worked it through, I found that the web service stuff sat better in the superclasses of the data I was dealing with. So I ended up with a superclass BasePostData, then if I was doing something special for a class (like linking in a relationship like you example) then I could do it in the subclass. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Do you know of any examples or links to the RestKit docs that handle many-to-many relationships with Core Data? -  I assume you mean with mappings between them in one JSON request, no, and no sure how you would do this. If it is with separate requests, I guess you could link them in code... but no examples sorry.

Comment: I don't mind the separate requests -- it's more that I was hoping RestKit had something that you could apply to a request to tell it that "All the things this request fetches? Treat them like they've got space=aSpaceID set", rather than having to do it in code in a completion block. Maybe I'm just expecting more magic than there is.